# Quick Algebric Trig question

Tags: trigonometry

The question is:

[image: 2 cos^2(x)-sin(x)-1 = 0]

I need to solve the equation for all values of x between 0 < x < 360

Now I got it to here and got a bit stuck:

[image: 2 cos^2(x)+cos(x)-2] = 0

Comment: Linear algebra is concerned with vector spaces of all dimensions and linear transformations between them.

Comment: HINT: Quadratic equation.

Comment: @DonLarynx Thanks! Yeah, I got to the the quadratic equation above however it wasnt really factoring down.

Comment: First equation isn't equivalent to second one. You should  replace $\cos^2(x)$ into $1-\sin^2(x)$. 2nd equation will become as $2(1-\sin^2(x))-\sin(x)-1=0$, or $2\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-1=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quadratic equation: $$cos(x) = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: I got to there. So all I need to do is arccos each of the x values and then get their values in degrees? Because thats what I thought I needed to do but im second guessing myself now:L

Answer (score 0):

Starting equation:
$$
2\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)-1=0 \tag{1}
$$

Applying identity 
$$
\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1,
$$
you'll transform equation $(1)$ to form
$$
2(1-\sin^2(x)) - \sin(x)-1=0;
$$
$$
-2\sin^2(x) - \sin(x)+1=0;
$$
$$
2\sin^2(x) + \sin(x)-1=0. \tag{2}
$$

Last equation is quadratic equation on $\sin(x)$.

There are $2$ solutions of quadratic equation $(2)$:

$$
\sin(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}, ~~~~~~~~~~\sin(x)=-1.
$$

So, there are $3$ solutions of trigonometric equation $(1)$, when $0<x<360^\circ$. Find them all...